# How to underline a substring in a Text in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swiftui

Is there a way to underline online a specific substring inside `Text` view in Swift UI?

```
// Code bellow will underline the ENTIRE string 
// Any way to underline on a specific substring?
Text("You must be invited by an....")
    .underline()
```

Here is specifically the UI I am trying to build:

[image]

Answer (score 13):

`Text(..)` views have a `+` operator that combines texts. Haven't looked how this magic works yet, but it does the job really well.

```
 Text("Regular text... ")
     + Text("underlined text!")
         .underline()
```

There is also as second way of doing this as well using a `underlined()` function on string:

```
 Text("Regular text... " + "undelined text!".underlined())
```

Super cool!

Comment: Thank you! So many posts saying it was impossible and that you need to write wrappers around attributed strings. This was what I needed.

Comment: I'm having an issue when using multiple of these in the same line. I have an M1 chip, but Xcode 12.4 forces me to run in Rosetta mode (Intel mode) to use SwiftUI. The compiler is slower in this mode, and it can't even preview the screen.
Also, the `underlined()` function doesn't exist?

Comment: Thanks, the second answer does not work and throwing error: `Value of type 'String' has no member 'underline'`

Comment: I confirm that the second solution looked amazing but doesn't work at all.

Comment: This will not work for multiline text

Answer (score 11):

What worked for me was using String Interpolation with other Text objects.

e.g.

```
Text("This sentence is not underlined. \(Text("But this sentence is underlined.").underline())")
```

Using this strategy I was able to  interpolate three different underlined Text objects within the original Text object without the compiler complaining.

Hope this helps!

Comment: notice this answer require iOS 14+

Comment: Seems broken in iOS 15; I get a display of `This sentence is not underlined. Text(storage: Swiftul.Text.Storage.any TextStorage (SwiftUl.(unknown context at
$189ebed68).LocalizedTextStorage), modifiers: [SwiftUl.Text.Modifier.anyTextModifier (SwiftUl. (unknown context at
$189e60fb8).UnderlineTextModifier)])` Any updates?

Comment: To clarify, the solution exactly as presented still works, but when I try to pass the string `"This sentence isn't \(Text("But this is.").underline())"` for the `Text(myString)` struct to display, I get the error above. If this only works with hard-coded sentences, it's not particularly more useful than `Text("a") + Text("b").underline`; the power would be in being able to use it in composing a string which is then passed to the UI.

Comment: An important note here is that this will make it difficult for translators to understand the context of your sentence if it is broken down in separate Strings. ie. `Text("This word is \(Text("underlined").underline()).")` would be "This word is %@", "underlined".

Comment: I tried on iOS 15.8.1 and it works fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to achieve it. I will mention using AttributedString()

```
func getAttributedString(string: String) -> AttributedString {
        var attributedString = AttributedString(string)
        attributedString.font = .body.bold()
        attributedString.underlineStyle = .single
        return attributedString
}
```

Here, in the function I have also added bold along with underline, you can add more styles. This can stay in the ViewModel class and call from View like this:

```
Text("You must be invited by an...." + model. getAttributedString(string: "apply to be on the waitlist"))
```

Or there is another way, you can create another function in ViewModel that would do what I have shown above like this.

```
Text(model.getString())  // put this in View

func getString() -> AttributedString {
    return "You must be invited by an...." + getAttributedString(string: "apply to be on the waitlist")
}
```